# No QVariant attributes

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using `from qtswitch import QtGui, QtCore` instead of the usual `from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore`, and there are some parts in which I am having trouble.

One of them is the error where in one of my function, I had it `return QtCore.QVariant()` and I keep getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QVariant'
```

and the opening sentence of the function is as follows:

```
def input(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
```

Any ideas? Or perhaps are there more documentations that I can read up on it?

Comment: Can you please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Will you please mention from where you get `qtswitch` module ?

Comment: @Shadow9043 I just placed in the function that was calling the error. Will this be good enough?

Comment: @dissidia By `custom` you mean its been implemented by you (or your company)? Or are there any public resources (documentation, download) available?

Comment: @Andreas It was actually implemented by my company, not me. I actually kinda narrow down the fact that QVariant seems to only be working under PyQt instead of PySide. Are there any other ways that I can reused the current code I have and just changed the `QVariant`?

Comment: Why dont you just `return None`? Is there a specific reason for using `QVariant` above?

Comment: @Shadow9043 If I am interpreting the code correctly (as I am editing the code), I need the `QVariant` as it links to another function that uses `toPyObject()`

Comment: May I add that I am trying to grab a selection (a list of names) in the combobox. The `toPyObject()` applies when user clicks on the OK button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your PySide version as PySide no longer supports QVariant. As found: [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt).

Please note on Python 3 or using `sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)` with PyQt4 you would get this error using `return QVariant()`:

```
TypeError: PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant represents a mapped type and cannot be instantiated
```

I would suggest moving away from using QVariant in this way.